# How to set session variable value as the value of input-field value?

Tags: php, html, session-variables

register.php

```
<?php

 $username = $_POST['user_name']; 
 session_start();
 $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
 header("Location: index.php");
 exit();
?>
```

// index.php

```
<?php 
  session_start();
  if(!isset($_SESSION['username'])){
      $_SESSION['username'] = "";
      }
 ?>

<html>
<span><?php echo $_SESSION['username'];?></span> <!-- This displays whatever is input in the field before submitting -->
<input type="text" name="user_name" value="<?php $_SESSION['username'];?>" required> <!-- This doesn't display anything -->
</html>
```

Once register.php is called and index.php is refreshed it should display the session variable as the value of the field. But for some reason it's not displaying. The problem is setting session variable as value of a input field. I can echo the same value in span and it works!

Comment: You missed the `echo` in `value="<?php $_SESSION['username'];?>"`

Comment: Strange I tried echoing earlier but didn't seem to work. But now it's working. Anyway Thanks!